# Microsoft Access - how to assign numerical values to multiple choice query

Tags: ms-access, label

I've been asked for help in a Microsoft Access database. However, there's been more than 10 years since I've used an Access database and I'm not sure if I can do what they asked me.

The database has several variables similar to this one:
*"How many times have you sneezed in the past week"

Never

One to Twice

Twice to Five

More than Five*

They want to analyse the data and convert the responses into 1, 2, 3 and 4 respectively. However, I'm not sure how to do this with Access. They need to keep also the text since collaborators are still uploading data and want to see the responses to the questions they've asked
1 - Never
2 - One to Twice
3 - Twice to Five
4 - More than Five

My question is: **is there a way to do this in Access?** Without messing up the data. I can easily convert these variables in any programming language but want to make sure there is no option in Access.

Thank you for your help! Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that a table of Reponses be created. In fact, perhaps that table already exists in the database?

Simply create a table with ID and ResponseText.

```
RID     ResponseText
1       Never
2       One to twice
Etc.
```

Now in any report or query, simply join in the above table as a left join and include the ID number. At that point, you have a query that includes both ResponseText, and the RID number.

And the beauty of the above is no code is required, you can add new values to the list over time (again without having to change the application).

So drop in the table with data into query builder, and then drop in above table. Now draw a join line from the text column in main table to the text column in above. You now have a “id” column that will display a number.

So no code is required, and using a query will translate these text values into numbers for you.

Comment: Hi! That's a good idea! That's actually how I do it in SQL. I will have a look into that option. Is it also possible to export only the numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using a calculated field in a query and the IIF statement.

something like

```
iif([sneezes]="Never",1, iif([sneezes]="One to Twice",2, iif([sneezes]="Twice to 5",3, iif([sneezes]="More than five",4,"ERROR"))))
```

replace [sneezes] with the field name for your data. You might need to replace "ERROR" with a number or whatever is appropriate.

The new query can include all the fields you need as well as this extra calculated one. The table is not changed at all. Then export the query if you need it outside access or just refer to it on a form or report. Exporting the query is the same as exporting the table.

Very similar to this answer [Am trying to categorise values using Ms Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36952421/am-trying-to-categorise-values-using-ms-access/36952534#36952534)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response! But that will also replace the text, right? I want to keep both text and number in Access and only export the number. Is there a way to do this? It's similar to create labels for each response

Comment: Thank you for your edit. I was looking for similar questions but haven't found. I will give it a go and if I have questions I will come back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use *Switch* which may be a little easier to handle than long *IIf* constructs:

```
ResponseCode; Switch([Response]="Never",1,[Response]="One to Twice",2,[Response]="Twice to Five",3,[Response]="More than Five",4)
```